# How to extract all drop down values from a data validated cell in excel to single cells for each value?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have a drop down list in Excel with 500 values in it. How do I get those values into single cells for each value? Basically, 500 values in 500 different cells from where I can use those values without having to search through the entire drop down.

NOTE: I can't use the data validation dialog because the values are referenced from another workbook which I don't have access to

Comment: Try this in a module to get the formula which should contain a name (named range): 'Sub ValForm(): Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Sheet1.Range("B4"): Debug.Print rng.Validation.Formula1: End Sub'. This is all one line. Then loop through each cell: something like Harun24HR proposed. You can post (in a comment) what the result of the Sub was for further guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have data validation in `A1` cell. Use following sub to extract validation list to `Column B` means from `B1, B1, B3 …..`

```
Sub ExtractValidationList()
Dim x() As String

   x = Split(Range("A1").Validation.Formula1, ",")
   For i = 0 To UBound(x)
        Cells(i + 1, 2) = x(i)
   Next

End Sub
```